# Trying to make 2 balls not collide with eachother but collide with walls around them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am making this game which is played by clicking on a white ball and you get points but if you click on a red ball it takes away points. I want the balls to collide with the walls around them but not eachother. I want the white ball to go behind the red ball. Using unity and c#. Happy for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must setup [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)

1) Assign the balls and walls to one layer, ex.: create the layer myObjects and then assign the balls and walls to that.

2) Uncheck the row, column that match the balls layers from Edit-> Project Settings -> Physics and then in the right panel expand the field "Layer Collision Matrix"

Comment: Adding to this, you can also [Ignore Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html).

Comment: As i know, layers are best performant in any case as number of objects and types (different prefabs/objects). Its not the same to process in the collision moment rather than an entire set of object in a layer. What do you think @ryeMoss ?